# Couldn't build wheel because of a package despite it already being installed windows

Tags: python-3.x, python-wheel, pycryptodome

I tried to pip install django-warrant and got the following error when it tried building the wheel for pycryptodome:

```
note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pycryptodome
  Running setup.py clean for pycryptodome
Failed to build pycryptodome
Installing collected packages: pycryptodome, envs, ecdsa, python-jose-cryptodome, django-extensions, django-crispy-forms, django-braces, warrant, django-warrant
  Attempting uninstall: pycryptodome
    Found existing installation: pycryptodome 3.11.0
    Uninstalling pycryptodome-3.11.0:
      Successfully uninstalled pycryptodome-3.11.0
  Running setup.py install for pycryptodome ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Running setup.py install for pycryptodome did not run successfully.
```

I already have pycrytodome pip installed, as well as the wheel package. I do not have pycrypto installed.

I'm on python 3.11.2 and on windows.